# How to define mapped type based on an array in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define this function

```
function magic(...propertyNames:string[]): { ????? : any }
{
....
}
```

In such away that returned type would have properties as listed in *propetyNames*?

For example:

```
type ResultType = {alpha:any, bravo:any};

let res = magic('alpha', 'bravo'); // res is compatible with ResultType
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that can make `magic` happen:

```
declare function magic<T extends string[]>(
  ...propertyNames: T
): Record<T[number], any>;

const result = magic("alpha", "bravo");

type ResultType = typeof result; // {alpha: any; bravo: any;}
```

Testing of `ResultType`:

```
const t1: ResultType = {
  alpha: "foo",
  bravo: 42,
  wannaBe: 3 // error (OK)
};
```

You could then further restrict the `any` type in `Record<T[number] any>` with an additional type parameter, as `any` doesn't provide any useful typing.

```
declare function magic<T extends string[], R>(
  ...propertyNames: T
): Record<T[number], R>;
```

#### Some explanation

- `T[number]` gives us all item values as union type. E.g.

```
type T = ["alpha", "bravo"]
type TItems = T[number] // "alpha" | "bravo"
```

- `Record` makes sure, that we have all item values `"alpha" | "bravo"` as property keys.
- The tuple type can be inferred with help of [generic rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsoBzLMAHgBV4QAPDEVYAZ3mYxi1WIG0BdAHwAKAFDx4AOikAHGDmkgYGAJ4A5KARDMAXPEoiAlLoBK4HDGBUeqZAQBGivgBp4UVMoEBuESLB528HDMyBAY8AC8hCRkQgBEUBDSABZQsS6xdjBQAG44sQbeIioK8KbBoZTKJZHFIDiIgVohGJ7wAPRt8ADeCclQum7KrZk5OAPungC+Pn6oARgAjCZNFVUIkV1irokpurGIOHlOWyO5ugAsAEzH4gDubqhQAEIgugDM7Z2KcjDwQgDyAGkDCJJoUims9BF4Dx4jtUulTnk+BCSpQAJIMAisSKUay2BwwPifeBwvqxeAAH1JSNiQA)