# How to preserve optional status of properties when wrapping generic interface

Tags: typescript

What I am trying to achieve is an `ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<T>` type that transforms the type of `T[K]` to `Timestamped<T[K]>` while still preserving if the property is optional or not.

```
interface ITimestamp {
  timestamp: number;
}

type Timestamped<T> = { data: T } & ITimestamp;

type ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Timestamped<T[K]>;
};
```

The issue I run into lies here:

```
class LocalStorageDataSource<T extends object> {
  public async load(
    keysToLoad: (keyof T)[]
  ): Promise<ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<Partial<T>>> {
    const data: ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<Partial<T>> = {};

    /** ... */

    return data;
  }
}
```

When setting `const data: ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<Partial<T>> = {};` I get the error "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'TimestampedProperties<Partial<T>>'."

And while this makes sense as I'm requiring all keys here: `[K in keyof T]: Timestamped<T[K]>;` I'm not sure how to keep the optional properties optional and the required ones required.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBVgFsIGcxxYAOyA3gLABQyyY2eBxAXMiAK5YBG0A3FQL5UqYAJ5EUmHPkLiAJgB50APmQBeMsllwCLdMn7IAZGkkMZfSsLEoA8pwBWEBGADqwMAAtT04hFkAFKAB7cSg6PEVkCAAPSBBZXGQghycwFXUKamQAbQBpZFBkAGsIESCYZHQAXV16HzlFPKqlC34LKgQAGzhcRIAZIIQ4ToBlMCCoOABzCAARbTgRoLYoJEiYuISklOcVTJoiNk5O4ARkHpEQM86guFkACioaGhKRXHQggbuWe9fyyoAlNkqk9kACWIEglhgLgIPI7I5nG5PN5GHJIaFwrh5P44GFgMNFEpiWRQTQEEEQPhNAsWAjUsivHU0X4MdAsTi8XRCcp0mQ2kIsjQAPQAKlFyAAdNLkKLhYLnsgoBAwCsQDSCBYaIJKPwgA)

Comment: That seems about right, since it is an actual ```{}```. You can assert the type of ```data``` with ```as``` - since you know more about the types than typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want the following:

- The function `load` should accept an array of property keys of whatever generic type `T` your instance of `LocalStorageDataSource<T>` has.
- The returned (awaited) object should reflect the properties of `T` that match the keys passed to the `load` function but mapped to a `Timestamped` property thereby preserving whether the original property was optional or not.
- I also assume that for every optional property `P` of `T`, you want the resulting property to be `Timestamped<P> | undefined` and not `Timestamped<P | undefined>`

If that is the case, I think I have a solution for you. I hope it helps.

### TL;DR

Here is a link to a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBVgFsIGcxxYAOyA3gFDLJjZ4HEBcyIArlgEbQDc5AvueTABPIikw58hUQBMAPOgB8yALxlk0uASbpkvZADI04ulJ6CRKAPLsAVhARgA6sDAALY5OIRpABSgB7USgaPHklVQoqAG0AaWRQZABrCCF-GGR0AF0mFhBpCBhQb2QIAA9IPNwM2MzkAH4M2k8ZWQBRUoQAGxZ8+RqAGmRc-MKQbwUlAB8hvIKi6WRtJvoW9BqFPgFhUWQAQSgoOCF0f2s7B3lB3ZLyiErkAApk1PT0AEoozPCySmRY+JAeyirA40Ey2WqMUyfDMXTguCqABl-Ag4J0AMpgfyHADmEAAIpo4Oj-CwoEh5DcKtIqv5bPYwEoKL8iCx2J1gAhkPChCAuZ1-HA5NcytSqk8UmkMh8vhKhLgTsihUxdm8mH5-FhgLgILIzgznG4PCtvBqgiFcLJ9odjqd6Rd0FcJkzflQEP4QPh1ESVGQ9PDuSAhGYqFQAPQAKgjyAAdHHkBGwwJQ8goBAwGTARoCNyqvqHIb3MspKaAubgKFrUcTvmwJc9hMeFR+PxyJHo+g6KAcdQLACYNA7kgE0nQJBYIgxHRUOBoPBh6R4tI6kwQZwoIMQIQIEx8FBu4NAjQPWiV8w2OvdAIHjy+Y83ioXW6PV6ab6xgB3ZDI1EYrG4gkiRJMkKU7fAZ3HecIAUB43ibZB3U9MBUzwFhOmQ1Q4A-OAXHUXAYwFIUHiiAAiLccBIwYSOAaQSMyODfm2FAACVUPQ9A+1UJipTTXA0LAHheDeAQgA) offering a solution. Note that `ResultType` has the desired properties. Key considerations are the modified mapped type `ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<T>`, a utility type `ArrayToObject<T, A extends (keyof T)[]>` and the function signature:

```js
type ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? Timestamped<Exclude<T[K], undefined>> | undefined : Timestamped<T[K]>
}

type ArrayToObject<T, A extends (keyof T)[]> = {
  [K in A[number]]: T[K]
};

class LocalStorageDataSource<T extends object> {

  public async load<A extends (keyof T)[]>(keysToLoad: A): Promise<ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<ArrayToObject<T, A>>> {
    const data = {} as any;

    /** ... */

    return data as ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<ArrayToObject<T, A>>;
  }
}

/** Testing type inference */
interface TestInterface { id?: number, name: string, optional?: number }

(async () => {
  const ds = new LocalStorageDataSource<TestInterface>();
  const result = await ds.load(["name", "id"]);
  type ResultType = typeof result;
})
```

#### Mapped type with optional properties

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69163943/12170167) you can check whether a type extends `undefined` the following way:

```js
type IsUndefined<T> = undefined extends T ? true : false
```

You can use that to modify your mapped type `ObjectWithTimestampedProperties` to react differently if the property is optional:

```js
type ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? Timestamped<Exclude<T[K], undefined>> | undefined : Timestamped<T[K]>
}
```

#### Array of property keys to object

Given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58216814/12170167) we can define a utility type that transforms an array of property keys to an object that contains those specified properties. To restrict ourselves to only allow keys of a specific object, we introduce another type parameter:

```js
type ArrayToObject<T, A extends (keyof T)[]> = {
  [K in A[number]]: T[K]
};
```

#### Function signature

We can now utilize both types to define our function signature. Note that we define an additional type parameter `A` as the array of keys of `T` passed into that function to derrive our mapped type. For the usage of the inner data object I wouldn't bother too much about type safety and simply use `any`. If you ensure a proper implementation, a cast for the returned object should suffice:

```js
  public async load<A extends (keyof T)[]>(keysToLoad: A): Promise<ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<ArrayToObject<T, A>>> {
    const data = {} as any;

    /** ... */

    return data as ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<ArrayToObject<T, A>>;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write up, was very informative :) I am curious about simplifying the `ObjectWithTimestampedProperties<T>` type to a generic  `Wrap<T, U>` where I envision `Wrap` would look something like this:
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzAHgCoBooFUoQB7AQB2AJgM5QCuRA1kQPYDuRaAfK1ALxWkQBmASyIQSuAsXJRUAKChyoAfmzIAongDGAG0okIaTNV2DhJdlAA+PI0JGz5ALmWpWAbiA)

However, I have been having issues with finding solutions for properly extending U in my tests so far.

(edit: added playground)